# $http Service Not Invoking and No Error in Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to write simple POC application, I am trying to load messages for a user but the $http service is not invoking even the controller is not loading. No errors in console. I am sure there must more easy way to implement this kindly suggest. My files are below kindly help, thanks in advance.

app.js file

```
'use strict';

var nkApp = angular.module("nkApp", [ 'ui.router' ]);

nkApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider.state('site', {
    'abstract' : true,
    views : {
        'navbar@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/navbar/partial-navbar.html'
        },
        'content@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/home/partials/partial-home.html',
            controller : 'homeCntrl'
        },
        'footer@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/footer/partial-footer.html'
        }
    }
}).state('home', {
    parent : 'site',
    url : '/home',
    views : {
        'content@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/home/partials/partial-home.html',
            controller : 'homeCntrl'
        }   
    }
}).state('messagesByUsername', {
    parent : 'site',
    url : '/trading-api/messagesByUsername',
    views : {
        'content@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/entities/trading/messages/partials/partial-messages-by-username.html',
            controller : 'messagesByUsernameCntrl'
        }
    }
}).state('messagesByUsername.list', {
    parent : 'site',
    url : '/trading-api/messagesByUsername/list',
    Params : {
      messages : null  
    },
    views : {
        'content@' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/entities/trading/messages/partials/partial-messages-list-by-username.html',
            controller : 'messagesListCntrl'
        }
    }
    });
});
```

messages-by-username.html

```
<div class="content">
<div ng-controller="messagesByUsernameCntrl">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="messagesFrm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input ng-model="username" class="form-control"         
type="text" id="formGroupInputLarge" placeholder="User ID"></input>
                </div>
                <a ui-sref="messagesByUsername" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">GO</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

message-by-username-controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module("nkApp").controller(
'messagesByUsernameCntrl',
[
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$state',
    '$stateParams' ,
    'messagesService',
    function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, messagesService) {

        $scope.username = "";
        $scope.messages = [];
        $scope.status = "";
        $scope.pageSize = 12;
        $scope.pageTitle = "Member Messages";

        $scope.getMemberByUsername = function(data) {
        console.log("Getting Messages For User : "
            + $scope.username);
        messagesService.getMemberMessagesByUsername(
            $scope.username).then(function(data) {
            console.log("Messages : " + data);
            $stateParams.messages = data;
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("Error Status : " + response.status);
            $scope.status = response.status;
        });
        }
    } ]);
```

messages-list-by-username.html

```
<div class="content">
<h3>Messages List</h3>
<div ng-controller="messagesListCntrl"> 
    <div ng-repeat="message in messagesList">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="page-header section-title">{{pageTitle}}
</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container content col-sm-2 col-lg-12">
                    <table class="row-border hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="150px">Username</th>
                                <th width="150px">FirstName</th>
                                <th width="150px">LastName</th>
                                <th width="150px">Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{member.username}}</td>
                                <td>{{member.firstName}}</td>
                                <td>{{member.lastName}}</td>
                                <td>{{member.email}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

messages-list-by-username-controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module("nkApp").controller('messagesListCntrl',
[ '$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    console.log("Params : " + $stateParams.messages);
    $scope.messagesList = $stateParams.messages;
} ]);
```

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="nkApp">
      <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet"    
    href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap- 
    theme.min.css">
     <link href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
   <body>   

<div ui-view="navbar"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</div>

<div ui-view="footer" class="footer"></div>

<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/
release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>     
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>

<script src="/app/components/home/controller/home-controller.js"></script>      


<script src="/app/entities/trading/messages/controller/
messages-by-username-controller.js"></script>
<script src="/app/entities/trading/messages/controller/messages-list-by-
 username-controller.js"></script>  
<script src="/app/entities/trading/messages/service/messages-service.js">
</script>   
</body>
```

messages-service.js

```
'use strict';

  angular.module('nkApp').factory('messagesService', [ '$http',

  function($http) {

 var service = {};
 var response = {};

 service.getMemberMessagesByUsername = function(username) {
 console.log("Getting Messages For User : [" + username + "]");
 response = $http.get("/trading-api/messages/" + username);
 return response;
 }
 return service;
   } ]);
```

Comment: Where do you define messagesService? Where do you make the $http calls ? I don't see that in your code? Try to build a fiddle/plunkr/jsbin/etc to make things easier to spot

Comment: just added service code now.

Comment: And console.log("Messages : " + data); doesn't return anything? No logs, nothing?

Comment: no there is nothing on console.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look and let me know if the problem persists. It shouldn't, but I haven't actually tested the code, just wrote it here in SO UI.

Answer (score 0):

In your service, add

```
.then(function(response) {
        return response.data})
```

to your `$http.get` call. Or change it to

```
return $http.get("/trading-api/messages/" + username)
  .then(function(response) { return response.data})
```

## Edit: I have changed your service to:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nkApp').factory('messagesService', messageService);

function messageService($http) {

    function getMemberMessagesByUsername (username) {
       return $http.get("/trading-api/messages/" + username).then(function(response) {
           return response.data || null;
       }, function(response) {
           return {};
       });
    };
    return {
        getMemberMessagesByUsername:getMemberMessagesByUsername 
    };
 };
```

## Edit2: In your controller call the service the way you did it before, such as:

```
......
messagesService.getMemberMessagesByUsername(paramYouPassHere).then(function(messages) {
   $scope.messages = messages;
}); 
......
```

Comment: No change, same issue. I am wondering its not even logging anything in console, I have tried console.log in both controllers.

Comment: Then create a fiddle with it and put the link here . Replace the backend url with anything you find on the web.. google as json api mock